# I need a no-arg constructor in my subclass, but superclass has defined constructor

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, superclass

I'm dealing with the Square super class. It has a defined constructor where it takes a double value for ***side***. I have to make a subclass that has a no-arg constructor that sets ***side*** to 10. If the super class does not have a no-arg constructor, is it even possible to do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
public class Square 
{
private double side;

public Square (double s)
{ 
     side = s;
}
}

public class MySquare extends Square
{   
private double area;

 public MySquare(double s){
  super(s);
```

}
}

Comment: Yes, that is possible. That is ***very*** basic task. What have you tried?

Comment: As this is a very basic task, a good answer to this question would amount to a tutorial.

Comment: I've tried many things, including having a constructor that takes no arguments. Like           public MySquare(){super();}. I also tried it with super(10) also. Still a no-go. Tried a conditional in the other constructor, trial and error style, but I think that was pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add a no-arg constructor to the subclass and invoke the superclass constructor with the correct value using the "super" method

```
public class Square {

    private double side;

    public Square(double s) {
        side = s;
    }
}

public class MySquare extends Square {

    private double area;

    public MySquare(double s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public MySquare() {
        super(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like a dummy...I tried adding my own no-arg constructor, with super() in the definition, but I didn't think about putting 10 in the (). Thanks a lot. Was really over thinking it.